# How to publish apps for trial version and renew payment after a period of time in google play

Tags: android, paypal, google-play-services

I developed an app which is working successfully on my device. Now I need to publish my app on *GooglePlay Store* (not for free), but I need to allow the users to download it freely and use the apps for trial period (ex 30 days), After that my app should to be renewed for payment.

How can I do that?

Thank you for your interest for posting your answer

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to force user to log into your app using an Account. After first login save entry date in a cloud. Then use In App Purchase for converting trial to full version.